# singleton and inheritance in Java

Tags: java, design-patterns, inheritance, singleton

I have a base class that captures some functionality common to two classes. In other words, I can create one base class and make these two classes subclasses of that base class. However, for each of these sub classes, the number of instances can be created is 1 (i.e. each sub class has to be a singleton).
I googled and found that there's a reasonable debate going on over this. Although there are several solutions available, I am not sure whether they would fit in my case.

can anyone tell me how I should design this?

Comment: Singletons are the Immortals of software. Supposedly *there can be only one*, yet we still hack at our code with swords, axes and sporks to make sure that happens...

Answer (score 2):

You can make each class separately a singleton, and make the base class abstract. Not sure what's the debate -- just that singletons, in general, aren't a great idea?

Comment: i dont think it is as easy as taht. see http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?InheritedJavaSingletonProblem

Comment: Yes, it is a dumb idea to try to implement "singletonhood" as an abstraction -- it does not work. As I said, though, no problems with two classes that just happen to share a base class both being implemented *separately* as singletons.

Comment: hhmmm, will try this out. well, people are talking about interfaces and factory patterns, and I was really confused

Comment: @sura It's an opinion (as long as I don't argument it, which I could), but the c2.com Wiki has become corrupted beyond usefulness. I consider this and sister places to be the next generation of c2.com, and that's why I hang out here, and rarely visit there.

Comment: "singletonhood as an abstraction" is one of the strengths of _inversion of control_ frameworks. The main use case is being able to easily change the implementation of a component when switching from development, to testing, to deployment platforms, or when deploying to different platforms.

Comment: This solution wrong in principal, although it may work in some cases.
I explain why in a comment to the solution i proposed above

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Abstract factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern). Have a separate class with methods to retrieve the singletons, and let it hold the references to the singletons in instance variables or in a map.

You may not want the increased complexity, but frameworks like [Spring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_framework) were created to solve these kind of issues (among others).

It seems that [Pico Container](http://picocontainer.org/) is alive and well, and it may be the simplest while still solid solution. Look at the *inversion of control* topics, and let the framework inject the singletons where you need them.

In short, don't try to make the singletons manage access to themselves. Delegate that on something else.

There's nothing inherently wrong in having singleton classes with complex inheritance. In fact, class hierarchies with private constructors (no instances) are very useful in many situations. You just have to decide how you want to manage the two important aspects of singletons: creation, and access.

Comment: I find this attitude -- entrenched as it may be -- just sad. We're telling this poor fellow that in order to avoid writing less than a dozen lines of code, he ought to include megabytes of jars, some XML configuration files, and create an application that can't be understood without a training class.

Comment: @Ernest I said "In short, don't try to make the singletons manage access to themselves. Delegate that on something else."

Comment: I also think that enforcing dependency injection for the sake of "modularity" is a wrong idea.

Comment: Neither *Abstract Factory* nor IOC (Inversion of Control) imply dependency injection, even if most IOC containers do it.

Comment: Spring does not solve this issue. it helps the issue if all the developers on your team get the instance via Spring. Bit if any one of them decides to do new on the class directly you're out of luck. The Singleton pattern was invented so that you don't need to ask for favors from your teammates. You code it in a way that no one can abuse it. It's easy to abuse it if you are only using Spring to enforce it.

Comment: i don't think you can create a class hierarchy if your base class has a single private constructor even if it has no arguments.

Comment: @inor The constructor in the ancestor classes would have to be ``protected``, yes.

Comment: @The only way to _try_ to avoid your code being abused is to keep it compiled, behind a firewall and other measures of security. The belief that one can avoid bad programming with language constructs and design patterns is the **myth** that makes the Java programming environment so bureaucratically inefficient.

Comment: @Apalala If your constructor is protected that class is no longer a Singleton. You can call it a Singleton and you can call it a Sheep, but a Singleton [pattern, by definition] must have a private constructor. Anyone can create an instance of a class whose constructor is protected, meaning you could have as many instances as your clients want... not just one. That's not a singleton!

Comment: @inor The patterns are about structure and use. They were developed (Smalltalk) and are used (Ruby) in languages with no access restrictions to class features. Singleton is characterized by users not calling the constructor but using a static method or service to access the single instance. Making the constructor protected (or private) enforces the pattern, but is not required.

Comment: @Apalala you can call anything you want a Singleton, but in the context of Design Pattern and especially Java, a Singleton Design Pattern is as described in the book Design Pattern by the GoF: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns

Comment: @inor Maybe if you read [the original book](http://www.amazon.com/Design-Patterns-Elements-Reusable-Object-Oriented-ebook/dp/B000SEIBB8/) you'd see that patterns are *patterns* and not recipes. Follow with patterns[in other languages](http://www.amazon.com/Design-Patterns-Ruby-Addison-Wesley-Professional-ebook/dp/B0010SEN1S/). Then you can read the proceedings of the [Pattern Languages of Program Design](http://www.amazon.com/Pattern-Languages-Program-Design-Coplien/dp/0201607344/) conferences to understand that patterns are not about the specifics of code.

Comment: @Apalala 1) The question is specifically about Java, 2) the book defines a Singleton "Ensure a class only has one instance, and provide a global point of access to it". So i say *** the code ensures that a second instance can not be created. *** Do you agree with that? If you disagree then we can just agree that we have two different definitions to the name. But in that case, I'm curious... Would you please explain what makes you want to call a class implementation, that allows creation of multiple instances of it, a Singleton?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you need an example but I gave it a try.  Without knowing any of your details this example is very vague.  I am also here to learn so let us know what you end up implementing.

The Base class:

```
  public abstract class BaseClass {

        public void someMethod() {
            System.out.println("base class hello: " + this);
        }

        public abstract void someOtherMethod(String value);
    }
```

One of the subclasses:

```
public class SubClassOne extends BaseClass {

    private static SubClassOne instance;

    private SubClassOne() {}

    public static SubClassOne getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new SubClassOne();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public void someOtherMethod(String value) {
        someMethod();
        System.out.println("sub class hello: " + value + " " + this);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SubClassOne one = SubClassOne.getInstance();
        SubClassOne two = SubClassOne.getInstance();
        SubClassOne three = SubClassOne.getInstance();
        SubClassOne four = SubClassOne.getInstance();
        one.someOtherMethod("one");
        two.someOtherMethod("two");
        three.someOtherMethod("three");
        four.someOtherMethod("four");
    }
}
```

Comment: Its just an example from the original question.  He mentioned he had one base class with common functionality and 2 subclasses that have to be singletons.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requirement: I had multiple cache maps with repeating methods and members, so I've created an abstract class like:

```
public abstract class AbstractCache<T> {

    protected final Map<String, T> cache;

    protected AbstractCache() {
        this.cache = getDefaultExpiringMap(TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(4));
    }

    public Map<String, T> getCache() {
        return cache;
    }

    public T getAll(String id) {
        return cache.get(id);
    }
}
```

Then I've extended this class and created a singleton instance:

```
public final class FooCache extends AbstractCache<Set<Integer>> {

    public static final FooCache INSTANCE = new FooCache();

    private FooCache() {
        super();
    }

    public void add(String fooId, Integer value) {
        cache.computeIfAbsent(fooId, k -> new HashSet<>()).add(value);
    }
}
```

And the usage:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    FooCache.INSTANCE.add("a", 1);
    System.out.println(FooCache.INSTANCE.getAll("a"));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not an expert in Java, so I don't know if this is technically legal Java code (perhaps another poster can comment):

Make the base classes inherit from a generic class Singleton.

Example:

```
class Singleton<T> {

    protected Singleton(); //constructor

    private static T _instance;

}

class DerivedOne extends Singleton<DerivedOne>{

    protected DerivedOne(){} //constructor
}

class DerivedTwo extends Singleton<DerivedTwo>{

    protected DerivedTwo(){} //constructor
}
```

Comment: you cannot do this, since the singleton has a private constructor.

Comment: @sura: Well you could hide the constructor using a "protected" access modifier instead of private modifier. This way, only subclasses can call it, but still not the outside world.

Comment: The thing with this idea is that you can only make one Object since you only have one _instance. If that's what you need, no problem but if you need exact one instance of each subclass, it's not possible this way.

Answer (score -1):

Inheritance is not the only way to re-use common functionality. Containment may be preferable in the general case.
Consider the following solution in which class A and B are the singletons, and the common functionality is in class AB, but instead of extending AB, both A and B use an instance of AB which is a singleton itself.

```
class AB { //common functionality of A and B
   //singleton pattern here
   //common data and functionality here
}
class A {
   private AB ab = AB.getInstance();
   //singleton pattern here
   //unique functionality and data of A

   //to use any of the functionality in AB delegate to member ab
}
```

class B is similar to A.

in this solution there is a single instance of every data and functionality of both A and B (and AB)

Note that if clients of A and B need to access the common public methods in AB, then 
AB, A and B should implement an interface of those public methods, and A and B implementation should delegate the call to ab.

---

The solution proposed by Ernest below, may be a shortcut in some situations, but in general is a wrong solution.

To explain why Ernest's solution may be wrong, let's describe that solution in a different way.
Suppose i have a singleton class A and i discover that i need to write another singleton class B, but i need some of the functionality of A in B. So i factor out the common data and functionality of A into an abstract class AB and make both A and B extend AB.
The reason why it's wrong, in general, is because this solution takes a subset of the data and functionality which is supposed to exist only once, and places it in a sub-class (AB), effectively and potentially duplicating it in every sub-class that will be created. Now, after getting an instance of A and an instance of B, you have two instances of the subset data and functionality in AB.

If for example, the common functionality placed in the base class writes some initial data to the file named "myData", then both of your singletons will execute this code even though it was only meant to be executed once, and when the later executes it it will wipe out the file created by the former.

Therefore, in general, the solution described here does not use inheritance, and ensures that a singleton encapsulates the common functionality as well as the singleton classes that use it.