# How to write a Singleton in proper manner?

Tags: java, multithreading, design-patterns, singleton

Today in my interview one interviewer asked me to write a Singleton class. And i gave my answer as

```
public class Singleton {

    private static Singleton ref;

    private Singleton() {
    }

    public static Singleton getInstance() {
        if (ref == null) {
            ref = new Singleton();
        }
        return ref;
    }
}
```

suddenly he told me this is old way of writing the class. Can any one please help me why he told like that.

Comment: Well it's not thread-safe, for one thing. You'd be better off using a static initializer - and consider using an enum with one value, which have various other benefits such as being serializable.

Comment: Before your next interview, you should read through "Effective Java". Chances are that your interviewer has its knowledge from the same book :-)

Comment: For interviews, I'd also read up on Spring Framework as that does a lot of singleton handling and is used a lot in server side work.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The first thing which comes to my mind when creating a singleton is `enum`. I generally use enum to implement singleton:

```
enum Singleton {
    INSTANCE;
}
```

One benefit you get with using enum is with Serialization.

With singleton class, you would have to make sure that serialization and deserialization doesn't create a new instance by implementing the `readResolve()` method, while this is not the case with enum.

Using class you should create the singleton like this:

```
public final class Singleton implements Serializable {
    // For lazy-laoding (if only you want)
    private static class SingletonHolder {
        private static final Singleton INSTANCE = new Singleton();
    }

    private Singleton() {
        if (SingletonHolder.INSTANCE != null) {
            // throw Some Exception
        }
    }

    public static Singleton getInstance() {
        return SingletonHolder.INSTANCE;
    }

    // To avoid deserialization create new instance
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private Singleton readResolve() {
        return SingletonHolder.INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

Comment: sir he asked singleton class should be final or not.what can i give answer for that

Comment: @user2775766. It's not hard and fast rule, but I would suggest to make it final, and try to avoid inheriting a singleton.

Comment: Because of the private constructor, the singleton class may not be subclassed, anyway. But declaring it as "final" makes it more obvious to the unwary programmer :-)

Comment: Why is SingletonHolder required?

Comment: @user1339772 That's there for lazy-loading, as already stated in comments there. With this, the instance will be created, only when first requested, and not at the time of class-loading, which happens, in case you just have a `static` field. But that is really not a major concern. You can avoid it.

Comment: @RohitJain - My bad, I should have cought this. Thank you

Comment: The benefits of using 'enum' is that: 'enum' implements **Serialization, Cloneable ** interfaces, However by cloning or by reflection or by deserialization we can not break the singleton. [https://sanjaymadnani.wordpress.com/2014/09/01/java-enumerations/]
Refer my blog on singleton design patter in java: [https://sanjaymadnani.wordpress.com/2014/04/14/singleton-design-pattern-in-java/]

Answer (score 15):

**Latest Standard Solutions:**

- Core java with Managed Beans / CDI

  ```
  @ApplicationScoped
  public class MySingleton { ... }
  ```
- EJB Lite (JEE6)

  ```
  @Singleton
  public class MySingleton { ... }
  ```

**Prior Recommendation (from 'Effective Java 2'):**

- Use an enum, with a single bogus enumeration constant e.g. INSTANCE.  Data fields and methods can be either static or non-static (instance) - the two behave equivalently, since there's only one instance
- Advantages:

  - Yep, it's a singleton.  Impossible to create more than one instance by any mechanism (within any given class loader on any JVM).
  - Singleton initialization is thread safe.
- Disadvantages (compared with above Standard Solutions):

  - The definition is a little obtuse - the 'enum' outer shell could misdirect inexperienced code maintainers.  It's a small hack, not the original intention of enum.
  - The implementation leaks through the abstraction. It violates the
    [Uniform Access Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_access_principle)

    - It doesn't work via injection - the client must know it is a singleton & code against the precise enum instance
    - The client must use Singleton.INSTANCE.someMethod()
    - The client can't (simply) code against an interface
    - The client's impacted by design changes between singleton to/from multi-instance objects
  - Extends an ancestor class (Enum), preventing inheritance from other classes
  - Serialization & deserialization just transfer the enum constant name without state - good for technically ensuring there's only one instance, but a null operation with regards to data.  In the (rare) event one wanted to share/synchronise singleton state across JVMs/class loaders, replication via serialization couldn't be used.

Answer (score 10):

You can do

```
public enum Singleton {
    INSTANCE;
}
```

and for a utility class which has no instances

```
public enum Utility {
     ;

     public static void method();
}
```

Comment: sir he asked singleton class should be final or not.what can i give answer for that

Comment: enum with no instances - wouldn't have thought about that. Nice :-)

Comment: @sourabh an enum is final. Singletons should be final ideally as there should only be one instance for which you shouldn't need more than one class.

Comment: Why using an enum instead of just a static class?

Comment: @Maxime Instead of an `enum` you can use a `static final class` with a `private` constructor, or you use an enum with no instances. I think an enum is simpler.

Comment: @PeterLawrey we can not use static at class level, isn't it?

Comment: @premraj correct. I meant a "static final MyClass" instance.

Comment: @Som Well If a class is singleton then final keyword doesn't matter for that class, However it is a good practice to keep the singleton class final. By the way Java 'Toolkit' class is singleton without having any private constructor: Refer example one of URL: [https://sanjaymadnani.wordpress.com/2014/04/14/singleton-design-pattern-in-java/]

Comment: @Premraj If calss is inside a class then this inner class can be static. At outer lever a Class can not be static in Java. This example I have mentioned in example 5 of my blog [https://sanjaymadnani.wordpress.com/2014/04/14/singleton-design-pattern-in-java/]

Comment: @Maxime The benefits of using 'enum' is that: 'enum' implements **Serialization**, **Cloneable** interfaces, However by cloning or by reflection or by deserialization we can not break the singleton. [sanjaymadnani.wordpress.com/2014/09/01/java-enumerations/]

Answer (score 8):

As others have already pointed out, the enum pattern is now widely considered a better approach to the Singleton vs. the old-school method, but I just wanted to point out a drawback.

We had a Singleton in the form of:

```
public enum Foo {
    INSTANCE;
}
```

that had been around for awhile, working just fine. Then during a code review, we saw this:

```
public enum Foo {
    INSTANCE,
    ANOTHER;
}
```

After we smacked him across the face with a wet mackerel, the coder in question had seen the error of his ways, and a larger than small amount of code had to be backed out and/or rewritten.  Yes, we caught it before it went out into production, but work had to be done to erase it.

I feel that this a weakness of this type of Singleton (albeit small and perhaps rare) vs. the old-school way.  Yes, you can break any pattern by implementing it wrong, but it seems a whole heck of a lot easier for a coder to break an enum Singelton than a well-formed old-school Singleton.

**EDIT:**

For completeness, here's an enum Singleton that guards against additional values getting added later:

```
public enum Foo
{
  INSTANCE;
  // adding another type here will cause a runtime

  static
  {
    if (Foo.values().length != 1)
    {
      throw new IllegalStateException("Not a Singleton.");
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is because your solution is not threadsafe.

The modern way is to tie the instance to an `enum` value:

```
enum Singleton {
    INSTANCE;
}
```

If you want to use lazy init of the instance then you can use the `ClassLoader` to guarantee thread safety:

```
public class Singleton {
        private Singleton() { }

        private static class SingletonHolder { 
                public static final Singleton INSTANCE = new Singleton();
        }

        public static Singleton getInstance() {
                return SingletonHolder.INSTANCE;
        }
}
```

More information [on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern#Example)

Answer (score 3):

He's probably look for this answer:

```
public class Singleton 
{
   private static Singleton ref;
   static
   {
       ref = new Singleton();
   }
   private Singleton()
   {
   }
   public static Singleton getInstance() 
   {
       return ref;
   }
}
```

Notice the static block. This approach is probably heavy since the instance is created upon class loading.

Comment: If this resolves your issue, the please feel free to accept it as the answer. But it's entirely upto you.....

Comment: sir he asked singleton class should be final or not.what can i give answer for that

Comment: You could replace the static block by a static field initializer expression (or however it's called).

Answer (score 3):

The Singleton I'd write would look like this:

```
@Service
class PersonService {
    // implementation here
}
```

But I also like the enum ideas. In reality, I never write (nor need) a Singleton other than one like the one above.

Comment: Correct. But it's still what I would use in practice, most of the time. Of course, depending on how Spring is configured, this doesn't have to be a Singleton, it can also be a prototype (a new instance).

Answer (score 3):

Why can't you do just

```
public class SingletonSandBox {

    private static SingletonSandBox instance = new SingletonSandBox();

    private SingletonSandBox(){
    }

    public static SingletonSandBox getInstance(){
        return instance;
    }

}
```

and test

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        SingletonSandBox sss1 = SingletonSandBox.getInstance();

        SingletonSandBox sss2 = SingletonSandBox.getInstance();

        System.out.println(sss1 == sss2);

}
```

As I know this is thread-safe and shorter than using static block. Again static field declaration is read earlier comparing to static block by the runtime.

Answer (score 3):

Some times We might have to Create one instance of a subclass only Like Java Toolkit class. **Example 1: Creating one instance of a subclass only** will be elaborating out it. Please Refer: [Singleton Design Patter in Java](https://sanjaymadnani.wordpress.com/2014/04/14/singleton-design-pattern-in-java/)

Answer (score 2):

From [What is an efficient way to implement a singleton pattern in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70689/what-is-an-efficient-way-to-implement-a-singleton-pattern-in-java)

Use an enum:

```
 public enum Foo 
 {
   INSTANCE;
 }
```

Joshua Bloch explained this approach in his book 'Effective Java'

Also check out [The better Java singleton pattern nowadays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5822827/the-better-java-singleton-pattern-nowadays)

Answer (score 2):

A thread safe version of the OPs initial approach, plus no one else dared to suggest a synchronized statement.

```
final class Singleton
{
    private static Object lock = new Object();
    private static volatile Singleton instance = null;
    private Singleton() { }
    public static Singleton getInstance()
    {
        if(instance == null)
        {
            synchronized(lock)
            {
                if(instance == null)
                {
                    instance = new Singleton();
                }
            }
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for unsynchronized check & lazy init (one could perhaps use the class itself as a lock object?)

Comment: @sam - something like synchronized(Singleton.class) {...}, I think the explicit lock object gives a semblance of readability, but using the .class literal won't hurt.

Answer (score 2):

This singleton implementation is called,

> *lazy initialization*

But the problem is this implementation is not a thread-safe one.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4362911/how-to-create-a-singleton-class?noredirect=1&lq=1), you can find the best thread-safe implementation.

There are few other popular Singleton implementations as well. One is,

> Eager initialization

```
final class EagerIntializedSingleton  {
    private static final EagerIntializedSingleton instance = new EagerIntializedSingleton();
    private EagerIntializedSingleton (){}
    private static EagerIntializedSingleton getInsance() {
        return instance;
    }  
}
```

But here, the instance of the singleton class is created at the time of class loading. (This is the default singleton class which is created by the IntelliJ IDE)

The next popular implementation is,

> Static block initialization

```
private static StaticBlockSingleton instance;
private StaticBlockSingleton(){}
static {
    try {
         instance = new StaticBlockSingleton();
    catch(Exception e) {
         .............
    }
}
```

This implementation is similar to eager initialization, except the instance of the class is created in the static block that provides the option for "exception handling". 
Both eager initialization and static block initialization creates the instance even before it's being used and that is not the best practice to use.

Answer (score 1):

It could be because it does not use "[double-checked-locking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking)" (as others have said) or it could also be because it is apparently possible to invoke a [private constructor using reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629706/java-accessing-private-constructor-with-type-parameters) (if the security policy allows it).

To invoke a constructor with no parameters pass an empty array.

```
package org.example;

public class Singleton {

    private static final Object LOCK = new Object();
    private static final Singleton SINGLETON = new Singleton();
    private static volatile boolean init = false; // 'volatile' to prevent threads from caching state locally (prevent optimizing) 

    private Singleton() {
        synchronized (LOCK) {
            if( init == true) {
                throw new RuntimeException("This is a singleton class!");
            }
            init=true;
        }
    }

    public static Singleton obtainClassInstance() {
        return SINGLETON;
    }

}


package org.example;

import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;

public class SimpleSingletonTester {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws NoSuchMethodException 
     * @throws SecurityException 
     * @throws InvocationTargetException 
     * @throws IllegalAccessException 
     * @throws InstantiationException 
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SecurityException, NoSuchMethodException, 
    IllegalArgumentException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException 
    {

        Class[] parameterTypes = {};
        Object[] initargs = {};
        Constructor<Singleton> constructor = Singleton.class.getDeclaredConstructor(parameterTypes);
        System.out.println( constructor.isAccessible() );
        constructor.setAccessible(true);
        System.out.println( constructor.isAccessible() );
        System.out.println( constructor.newInstance(initargs) );
        System.out.println( constructor.newInstance(initargs) );

    }

}
```